# Cannot set text to TextView in PopupWindow

Tags: android, html, popup, textview, window

I created a popup window to show a disclaimer in my app but I can't figure out why i cannot set text to TextView. It is an HTML string so I did this:

```
private void showPopup(final Activity context) {
    final PopupWindow pwindo;
    Button btnClosePopup;

    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tos_text)));

        btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pwindo.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**popup_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#4d4d4d"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="tos_text"><![CDATA[
    <p>This is a html-formatted string with <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph of the same string.</p>
    ]]>
</string>
```

It works only if I add `android:text="@string/tos_text"` in the XML file, but i see the raw html codes. What could be the problem?

Comment: It should almost certainly be `TextView txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtView);` 
Note the addition of `layout.`

Comment: Can you tell me how to add scrollbar in this case? I tried to search here on SO but i do not find nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next:

```
    private void showPopup() {
            //if you call this method correctly then you do not need to wrap 
            // this method by try-catch block which affects performance

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element), false);

            final PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

            //get txt view from "layout" which will be added into popup window
            //before it you tried to find view in activity container
            TextView txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tos_text)));

            //init your button
            Button btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pwindo.dismiss();
                }
            });

            //show popup window after you have done initialization of views
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

To add scrollable content you need to change approach of initialization of popup window:

```
final PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
```

where you need to change width of window to ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.

Then you need to wrap your text view by ScrollView which has root child - LinearLayout:

**popup_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/popup_element"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#4d4d4d"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10sp">

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Close"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ScrollView has field with weight:
android:layout_weight="1"
I have added this to avoid hiding of button when text will fill all of visible content.

**EDIT 2:**

Also you can fix height of scroll view, if you do not want to fill all the screen:

**-----**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
```

**-----**

Comment: Try explaining your code, please. It benefits everyone

Comment: Yes, it works. Can i ask you how to add scrolling to this popup? The text is too long...